# Sails.js: Running grunt watch task in production

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, sails.js, grunt-contrib-watch

I want to run the exact same grunt watch task in production mode that's run in development mode. I thought it would be as simple as adding the watch task to the "prod.js" task in `tasks/register/prod.js`, but doing that hangs Sails upon lift.

How do I run the watch task in production?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to do this?

Comment: My application allows users to, in some sense, "upload" new pages to the app, so I need Grunt to watch and recompile assets as they get moved into assets, otherwise the app will need to be restarted to reflect new changes.

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I run the watch task in production?

I have found out recently that sails (v.0.11.0) restricts grunt executions in production mode before startup. To fix this problem, you need to change a few lines in /node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/grunt/index.js

Specifically, comment the lines:

```
// Fire finish after grunt is done in production
/*if(sails.config.environment === 'production'){
  cb_afterTaskStarted();
}*/
```

comment and add:

```
// Go ahead and get out of here, since Grunt might sit there backgrounded
/*if(sails.config.environment !== 'production'){
 cb_afterTaskStarted();
}*/
cb_afterTaskStarted();
```

Comment: is there a way to go about this that doesn't involve editing files in node_modules. i pull to my server from git and run npm install, node_modules is not watched by git. Any way other than this would be appreciated